# Center text/character inside div with horizontal offset without nesting additional elements

Tags: html, css

I have a `div` with some fancy non-repeating background (figure 1) and I want to place a text (in fact, 1 or 2 characters) inside it. The background is asymmetrical, so I want to center the text relative to a portion of the image (figure 2). Ideally I want it to look like in figure 3.

[image]

I managed to get vertical positioning done by

```
div.button {
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 72px;
    padding-top: 0;
}
```

However, I can't get it centered horizontally the way I want: `text-align: center` makes it look like in figure 4 (i.e. centered relative to entire `div` width) and `padding` values have no effect.

I know I can nest another `div` inside, size it appropriately and place my text inside. But is there a way to get this done without nesting any additional elements? The matter is that I have hundreds of those generated on my page and all of them have event handlers, so I'd rather tolerate ugly text centering than have to deal with additional nested elements.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qnxs2ky5/

Comment: Did you try to add a padding-right to the div.button css rule ?

Comment: Is that something like that ? https://jsfiddle.net/bcnwauxw/

Comment: You have a couple of options. 1. Use a custom padding / margin for the text to align it exactly, however this will have to be done manually for each one. 2. Create a div the size of the area of the image, and add your text inside that (centered). There is no CSS property to align relative to image coordinates, only to other elements.

Comment: Will the background image be consistent across all tiles? In reference to Druzion's comment above, some padding might be the only way to fix this. You'd just have to lower the width to accommodate. https://jsfiddle.net/qnxs2ky5/4/

Comment: The background and dimensions of all tiles are the same. The text will be different in each one, sometimes font and font size. Looks like, adding padding-right to compensate the rest of the image and subtracting it from width works!! Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For some weird reason you can add `text-indent` to move the letter to the left;

```css
div.tile {
  width: 88px;
  height: 123px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 72px;
  line-height: 104px;
  color: #FF0000;
  text-indent:-10px;
  background-image: url('data:image/gif;base64,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');
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="tile">i</div>
</body>
```

For your example -10px look perfect, but I suppose that you could use `em` as well to be more flexible.

Comment: Unfortunately, I believe this effect of `letter-spacing` is the result of incorrect browser implementations, and I don't think it would work reliably across browsers.

Comment: @torazaburo `text-indent` will work on the other hand. Why do you believe that?

Comment: Yes, I think `text-indent` is the proper solution. Your suggestion is based on behavior that `letter-spacing` is applied to the right of the last character in the string, which appears to be the case at least in Chrome, but actually is **not** compliant with the spec (which says that the spacing should only be applied **between** characters in the string, which means in this case, since there is only one letter, not at all. So when this "bug" is fixed in Chrome, your "solution" using `letter-spacing` will stop working. In other words, the "weird reason" you refer is a bug in Chrome.

Comment: @torazaburo I suppose you are right, I changed the answer to only use `text-indent`. Thanks for the research!

Comment: I think this is a better solution than `padding-right` and `width` combination because this way I can keep `width` exactly equal to width of my background.